# woocommerce api v2 returns uncaught exception

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-rest-api

Using wc-api (https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php)

My client function: (literally the same as in docs)

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    $store_url, // Your store URL
    $consumer_key, // Your consumer key
    $consumer_secret, // Your consumer secret
    [
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v2', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
        'query_string_auth' => true // Force Basic Authentication as query string true and using under HTTPS
    ]
);
```

and when I try with

```
$results = $woocommerce->get('');
```

or

```
$results = $woocommerce->get('products');
```

or any other endpoint it gives me:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException
>
> Message: Error: No route was found matching the URL and request method
>   [rest_no_route]

If I change the version to 'wc/v1' it is working ok.

Do I need to add some other plugins or additional code to make v2 work?

Answer (score 0):

Try send your request like this, with your creds in param :

```
$res = ($woocommerce->get('orders?status=processing&consumer_key=ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&consumer_secret=cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
```

Comment: Returned proper data as v1, but gave me similar error on v2. Anyway, a week later after the question there was an update that fixed it automatically. Thanks for your answer.